# How can I prevent Linq2Sql from negating bit columns when comparing to boolean false?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql, boolean

One very annoying feature of Linq2Sql is that when comparing a `BIT` column with a boolean `false`, the generated T-SQL for some reason always negates the evaluation, i.e. something like:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeType
(
  MyInt INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  MyBool BIT NOT NULL
)
```

Which Linq has mapped to the type:

```
public class SomeType
{ 
  public int MyInt {...}
  public bool MyBool {...}
}
```

With a Linq query against that table like:

```
var db = new MyLinqContext(...);
var q = db.SomeTypes.Where(x => !x.MyBool);
```

Will always generate something like:

```
SELECT [t0].[MyInt], [t0].[MyBool]
FROM [SomeType] AS [t0]
WHERE (NOT ([t0].[MyBool] = 1))
```

This stupid and backwards `(NOT (field = 1))` construction has a tendency to mess up my query plans and indexes, but Linq2Sql seems hellbent on doing it the complicated way rather than using the more index-friendly and straightforward `(field = 0)`.
You might be tempted to try some variations, such as:

```
var b = false;
...Where(x =>
x.MyBool == false ||
x.MyBool != true ||
x.MyBool == b ||
!!!x.MyBool
```

...or even more exotic tricks, but they all translate to the same `(NOT (field = 1))` or worse.

*Is there a secret way to encourage Linq2Sql to generate a straight, non-negated boolean comparison without messing with the DBML or the mapped properties?*

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL or EF?

Comment: @mjwills It's plain old Linq2Sql

Answer (score 0):

I'm only writing all this to share the word. After trying just about every imaginable way, I've come sort of close. Here's my best shot so far:

```
var q = db.SomeTypes.Where(x => x.MyBool.CompareTo(0) == 0);
```

While it's unintuitive, it will generate T-SQL like:

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
SELECT [t0].[MyInt], [t0].[MyBool]
FROM [SomeType] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[MyBool] = @p0
```

Unfortunately we've lost the literal comparison, but we've also removed the scalar operation, which can make a ton of difference in a quirky query plan. Obviously the comparison is now between an `INT` parameter and a `BIT` column, but the Query Optimizer seems to find those data types perfectly compatible.

Amusingly, while this is apparently the only way to generate straight T-SQL, the same code would fail with an ArgumentException if evaluated directly in the .Net CLR:

```
var x = new SomeType();
x.MyBool.CompareTo(0); // ArgumentException: Object must be of type Boolean.
```

But oh, the things we do for query plans...

Comment: Apparently if you can use `CompiledQuery.Compile(` then it will change LINQ to SQL's translation of boolean tests.

Comment: Good input, unfortunately I can't always use Compile(). But I'll keep it in mind for future projects, thanks!